# Database failure. Please refer to sugarcrm.log for details

Tags: sugarcrm

I am getting this:

> Database failure. Please refer to sugarcrm.log for details

My sugarcrm.log:

```
SET name='testculoare',date_modified='2016-06-14 07:30:55',modified_user_id='1',created_by='551263d1-84a2-7f9f-51d8-5735bbb30959',description=NULL,**assigned_user_id='',=NULL**
                     WHERE  imob_raport_imobiliar.id = '3727f06e-1ea3-4564-374c-575e8d0d4648' AND deleted=0: MySQL error 1064:

 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '=NULL
                     WHERE  imob_raport_imobiliar.id = '3727f06e-1ea3-4564-374c-575e8d0d4' at line 2
```

Answer (score 2):

This is usually caused by missing entries in the fields_meta_data table which can be caused if you move over the SugarCRM files but don't move over the database.

This can also be caused by customisations of fields that no longer exist.

You can check the cached vardefs for the module in `cache/modules/ModuleName/ModuleNameVardefs.php`. Any vardefs with a missing name value will cause this issue (I've also wrote a [script](http://www.jsmackin.co.uk/suitecrm/suitecrm-missing-field-definitions/) to do this for SuiteCRM).

Once you have found the field that is causing this you can usually comment out any lines that are causing the empty definition.